# Why is my dict getting deleted during a dict comprehension constructor?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm referencing one dict, `protocol_dict`, in the dict comprehension construction of another:

```
    for drug_id in drug_dict.keys():
        drug_name = Drugs.get_drug_name_from_id(drug_id)
        
        # Error happens here:
        frontend_forward_dict[drug_name] = {pid: protocol_dict[pid] for pid in drug_dict[drug_id]}
```

When I run this code, I get the error message that `protocol_dict` is not defined. Yet it clearly is, and moreover, when I debug my code, I can verify that python has a stored value for `protocol_dict` right up until it runs the dict comprehension. But the dict comprehension throws this error the very first time it's called.

When I replaced the dict comprehension with a for-constructor, the problem vanishes, and everything works as expected:

```
    for drug_id in drug_dict.keys():
        drug_name = Drugs.get_drug_name_from_id(drug_id)
        target_dict = {}
        for pid in drug_dict[drug_id]:
            target_dict[pid] = protocol_dict[pid]
        frontend_forward_dict[drug_name] = target_dict
```

Does anyone know what's going on here? In case it's useful, here's the definition of `protocol_dict`:

```
protocol_dict = {}
    for p, val in protocol_data.items():
        versions = []
        if len(val) == 1:
            if "VERSION NUMBER" in val[0]["metadata"].keys():
                vers = val[0]["metadata"]["VERSION NUMBER"]
                versions.append(vers)
            else:
                versions.append("-1")
        else:
            # Multiple versions. Can assume each one comes with the right tag.
            for version in val:
                vers = version["metadata"]["VERSION NUMBER"]
                versions.append(vers)
        protocol_dict[p] = versions
```

Comment: You could provide some sample input along with expected output for getting a better understanding of the question.

Comment: you mentioned `protocol_list` rather than `protocol_dict` in the first part - is it possible that you just have the wrong name in your comprehension?

Comment: Please check your description again, and make sure to provide a [mcve]. The question currently has several contradictory and missing parts. E.g. it says "I'm referencing one dict, ``protocol_list``" but there is no ``protocol_list``, only ``protocol_dict``; its says "Yet it clearly is [defined]" without showing that. Please also include the exact error message and traceback.

Comment: Oops, thanks everyone. `protocol_list` was a typo in this post, not in the code. Typo fixed.

Answer (score 0):

**protocol_dict** needs to be defined before the code that is using it.

Is it defined in the same file, or is it imported?

If it is in the same file then it needs to be in the same scope, you might be defining the **protocol_dict** in such way that it is not visible by the code that is trying to use it.

There is nothing magical about the dict comprehension, you can test it by running this snipet:

```
foo = dict(a=1, b=2)
print({x: foo[x] for x in "ab"})
```

Comment: Thanks, using `protocol_dict` was actually a typo (in the post, not the code). You can see in the problem statement that `protocol_list` was defined up until I called the dict comprehension, at which point python said that it was undefined.